# If $E \subset R$ and $m(E) \gt 0$ , can we find a surjective function that maps $E$ to $R$ ?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $m(E)=0$ , then $E$ the cardinality can be rather large . How about the inverse condition ? If $E \subset R$ and $m(E) \gt 0$ , then we can assert that $E$ is uncountable . But can we find a surjective function that maps $E$ to $R$ ? Or if $m(E)=a \gt 0$ , can we find such a surjective function $f$ maps $E$ to $(0,a)$ ?

Comment: If you are willing to assume continuum hypothesis then there is always a surjection from any uncountable set in $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$.. Your second question follows trivially from the first  because $(0,a)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Without CH, would it be possible to have a set of nonzero measure with cardinality less than continuum?

Comment: @Berci  No, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $m(E)>0,$ then there exists a binary system of pairwise disjoint compact subsets of $E$ of positive measure: We start with disjoint $K_0,K_1\subset E.$ Then we split $K_0$ into disjoint $K_{00}$ and $K_{01},$ and split $K_1$ into disjoint $K_{10}$ and $K_{11}.$ All these sets have positive measure so we can keep going, a la Cantor. See [binary tree](https://www.google.com/search?q=infinite+binary+tree&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3z-eljMjfAhX-GDQIHWumAmMQ_AUIDigB&biw=1155&bih=681)

Every binary sequence generates a nested sequence of compact sets as above. For example $0,1,1,0,1,0,\dots$ generates

$$K_0,K_{01},K_{011},K_{0110},K_{01101}, K_{011010},\dots $$

These sets are nested, compact and nonempty. Hence their intersection is nonempty. Since the set of binary sequences has the cardinality of $\mathbb R$ we end up with with $\mathbb R$ many nonempty pairwise compact subsets of $E.$ Therefore the cardinality of $E$ is at least that of $\mathbb R .$ Schroeder-Bernstein then shows the cardinality of $E$ is the cardinality of $\mathbb R.$